# Updating entity - dirty checking vs repository save method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I've seen that programmers use two different ways to update entity:

First method is to make service update method transactional and using hibernate dirty checking. This is simple update and User class doesn't contains any lazy collections.

```
@Transactional
public void updateUser(Long id, String name) {
    User user = userRepository.find(id);
    user.update(name);
}
```

Second way use method save from spring-data.

```
public void updateUser(Long id, String name) {
    User user = userRepository.find(id);
    user.update(name);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Which way should I use for that simple update?

Comment: this question is primarly opinion based -> so it's off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify an object that is known by the hibernate session, it will automatically be saved by hibernate when session is flushed.
I would advise against this because in your code you don't know if you are using hibernate or another ORM. Additionally, if your object is not in the session when you modify it, it will not be saved. So always call save explicitely to make sure your object is saved.